# Resteasy and Jackson ignoring JAXB annotations

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, jackson, resteasy

I am in the process of converting an Ant RestEasy project to Maven.  I have most everything up an running again, with one problem.  The JSON output is not working like it did before.  For example, here is a simple entity which gets output:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "site-recode")
public class SiteRecode {
    @XmlElement(name = "site", required = true)
    protected String _site;
    @XmlElement(name = "hist", required = true)
    protected String _hist;
    @XmlElement(name = "ks_and_meso", required = true)
    protected Boolean _withKsAndMeso;
    @XmlElement(name = "site-group", required = true)
    protected String _siteGroup;

    public SiteRecode() {
    }

    public SiteRecode(String site, String hist, Boolean withKsAndMeso, String siteGroup) {
        this._site = site;
        this._hist = hist;
        this._withKsAndMeso = withKsAndMeso == null ? Boolean.TRUE : withKsAndMeso;
        this._siteGroup = siteGroup;
    }

}
```

and here is the context resolver I use for RestEasy:

```
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class JacksonContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    private ObjectMapper _objectMapper;

    public JacksonContextResolver() {
        _objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        _objectMapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector());
    }

    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> objectType) {
        return _objectMapper;
    }
}
```

Under our old Ant builds both JSON and XML output worked great.  XML output still works perfectly.  Now I get this exception if I try to get JSON:

> Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class com.imsweb.seerapi.siterecode.SiteRecode and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) )

I've found out 2 things.

- If I change the fields from protected to public I get output.  However the names are wrong (ignoring the names in the annotations):

`{
    "_hist": "9650",
    "_site": "C379",
    "_siteGroup": "33011",
    "_withKsAndMeso": true
}`

- Another thing that kind of works is adding getters and setters and moving the @XmlElement annotations to there.  I don't get the exception anymore, but the names are based on method names and not annotations:

`{
    "hist": "9650",
    "site": "C379",
    "siteGroup": "33011",
    "withKsAndMeso": true
}`

So basically it is completely ignoring my annotations.  It will show the default named fields/methods if they are public.

However the XML output still works perfectly and honors the annotation names:

```
<site-recode>
    <site>C379</site>
    <hist>9650</hist>
    <ks_and_meso>true</ks_and_meso>
    <site-group>33011</site-group>
</site-recode>
```

I've Looked at the produced WAR files from both Ant and Maven and I can't figure out what I am doing differently.  Has anyone seen something like this?  Thanks.

Update:

I figured it out.  I had forgot to set up the manifest correctly in the pom.xml.  I just need to add:

```
<manifestEntries>
     <Dependencies>org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-xc,org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-mapper-asl,org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-core-asl,org.apache.commons.logging export,org.apache.log4j export</Dependencies>
</manifestEntries>
```

Comment: Nice! Are you able to post and accept an answer yourself?